# Build extension spree e-commerce

Tags: ruby, e-commerce, spree

I'm with one problem when executed the [step 5.7](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/creating_extensions.html). In my extension not metting the path:

```
#lib/spree/flag_promotion_configuration.rb.
```

I must create the directory 'spree' and after create the file 'flag_promotion_configuration.rb' ?

If I write this in the file, as the tutorial required:

```
#lib/spree_flag_promotions/engine.rb

module Spree::ActiveShipping; end 

.... 

module SpreeFlagPromotions
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    initializer "spree.flag_promotions.preferences", :after => "spree.environment" do |app|
      Spree::FlagPromotions::Config = Spree::FlagPromotionConfiguration.new
    end

   ....

  end

end
```

And I executed:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Return this error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Spree::FlagPromotions

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I believe it has anything to do with:

```
#lib/spree/flag_promotion_configuration.rb.
```

Because they do not know where to create this file is or where.